# Got UnsatisfiedLinkError when start Spark program from Java code

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop2

I am using SparkLauncher to launch my spark app from Java.The code looks like

```
Map<String, String> envMap = new HashMap<>();

        envMap.put("HADOOP_CONF_DIR","/etc/hadoop/conf");
        envMap.put("JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH", "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hadoop/lib/native");
        envMap.put("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hadoop/lib/native");
        envMap.put("SPARK_HOME","/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/spark");
        envMap.put("DEFAULT_HADOOP_HOME","/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hadoop");
        envMap.put("SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH","all jars under /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/jars");
        envMap.put("HADOOP_HOME","/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/hadoop");


        SparkLauncher sparklauncher = new SparkLauncher(envMap)
                .setAppResource("myapp.jar")
                .setSparkHome("/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.5.1-1.cdh5.5.1.p0.11/lib/spark/")
                .setMainClass("spark.HelloSpark")
                .setMaster("yarn-cluster")
                .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "2g")
                .setConf("spark.driver.userClassPathFirst", "true")
                .setConf("spark.executor.userClassPathFirst", "true").launch();
```

Every time, I got

> User class threw exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.maxCompressedLength(I)I

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your jar is including Spark/Hadoop libraries that have conflict with other libraries in the cluster. Check that your Spark and Hadoop dependencies are marked as provided.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer? 
and found something similar on https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Advanced-Analytics-Apache-Spark/Override-libraries-for-spark/m-p/32146#M1142

Comment: Somehow your jar is overriding Cloudera inner libraries, like ```snappy-java```. This makes inner process complain because they are expecting their own libraries. Or maybe the classpath ordering is being affected by the ```userClassPathFirst``` flag - remember it's "experimental" (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html).